# Safely delete file in Matlab, without risking deletion of other files or execution of arbitrary code

Tags: matlab, security, file-io, delete-file

How do I safely and programmatically delete a file in Matlab? By 'safely', I mean:

1. A single deletion statement deletes at most one file, e.g. no wildcards. `delete(a*)` should remove the file `a*` and nothing else!
2. A single deletion statement shall not have any possible side-effects, e.g. no `system(sprintf('rm -f %s', foo))` where `foo` may be `file;some_command`.

Currently, the code I encountered has `system(sprintf('rm -f %s', foo))` where there is some sanitation of `foo`. I wanted to replace it by `delete(foo)`, but according to [documentation](http://www.mathworks.se/help/techdoc/ref/delete.html), Matlabs `delete`-function accepts wildcards, so requirement (1) is not met; if the input contains `*`, I might end up deleting many files. How can I safely delete a file in Matlab?

Of course, one way would be to sanitise `foo` by removing characters such as `:=, ()*<>!?%;`. But firstly this is a roundabout way, and secondly that doesn't allow me to remove files that contain those characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way I can think of is to go through Java. As you probably know you can make Java statements directly from Matlab.

Also consider [escaping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character) the special characters instead of removing.

Answer (score 2):

How about something like:

```
function safe_delete(filename)
    %# listing
    d = dir(filename);
    d([d.isdir]) = [];   %# only files

    %# skip if more than one match or no match
    if isempty(d) || numel(d) > 1, return; end

    %# delete file
    p = fileparts(filename);
    delete( fullfile(p,d(1).name) );
end
```

This will delete exactly one file. If there are more than one match, the function doesn't delete any files.

#### Examples:

```
safe_delete('file.txt')           %# delete file.txt if it exists
safe_delete('/path/to/file.txt')  %# also works with relative/absolute paths
safe_delete('*.txt')              %# doesn't do anything
safe_delete('/path/to')           %# doesn't delete directories only files
```

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by *safely delete* ?  If you want a prompt to ask *Are you sure you want to delete ... ?* well, Matlab (like C, C++, Perl, Python, *etc, etc*) gives you the tools to write a function which safely wraps a call to `delete`.  With a little string manipulation you could write your function to catch only attempts to call `delete` with wildcards

Or perhaps the `recycle` option for `delete` is what you are looking for.

Also, check out `File | Preferences` and on the dialog box that opens see the `Deleting files` option at the bottom.

Comment: I have clarified my question. I don't want any prompt, I just want a call as direct as possible to the equivalent of `unlink`; no prompts, no wildcards, no interactive file dialogs, no recycle-bin, just a simple and direct deletion of a single file.